# Отсортировать массив по количеству гласных букв в порядке возрастания

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка

Всем привет, есть такой код, считывающий массив и сортирующий слова в нём в порядке возрастания:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 
  
// Function to check the Vowel 
bool isVowel(char ch) 
{ 
    ch = toupper(ch); 
    return (ch == 'A' || ch == 'E'
            || ch == 'I' || ch == 'O'
            || ch == 'U'); 
} 
  
// Returns count of vowels in str 
int countVowels(string str) 
{ 
    int count = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) 
        if (isVowel(str[i])) // Check for vowel 
            ++count; 
    return count; 
} 
  
// Function to sort the array according to 
// the number of the vowels 
void sortArr(string arr[], int n) 
{ 
    // Vector to store the number of vowels 
    // with respective elements 
    vector<pair<int, string> > vp; 
  
    // Inserting number of vowels 
    // with respective strings 
    // in the vector pair 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
  
        vp.push_back( 
            make_pair( 
                countVowels( 
                    arr[i]), 
                arr[i])); 
    } 
  
    // Sort the vector, this will sort the pair 
    // according to the number of vowels 
    sort(vp.begin(), vp.end()); 
  
    // Print the sorted vector content 
    for (int i = 0; i < vp.size(); i++) 
        cout << vp[i].second << " "; 
} 
  
// Driver code 
int main() 
{ 
    string arr[] = { "lmno", "pqrst", 
                     "aeiou", "xyz" }; 
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); 
  
    sortArr(arr, n); 
  
    return 0; 
}
```

К сожалению, преподаватель запрещает использовать **векторы и классы** :(
Подскажите, как переделать без них?

Comment: `запрещает использовать классы`. Он точно вам не Си преподаёт?

Comment: Использовать собственную структуру для хранения строк и количества гласных. Если нельзя `sort` - есть `qsort`...

Comment: @vp_arth 2 семестр, считается, что не проходили ещё их, поэтому нельзя

Comment: Покажите преподу: [Kate Gregory. Stop teaching C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk) Может не на вашем, так на следующем курсе за ум возьмётся)

Answer (score 1):

А какая разница вектор или массив?

В общем разницы между вектором и массивом нет, просто у вектора вы указываете начало и конец через `begin()`, `end()`, а в массиве указываете начало массива и конец через `array + size`

**вариант 1:**

тут правда используется лямбда-функция и вообще stl

```
const int arr_size = 10;
char** arr = new char*[arr_size];

// сортировка массива

std::sort(arr, arr + arr_size, [](const char* a, const char* b) {return strcmp(a, b) < 0; });
```

**вариант 2:**

а тут используется вообще голый c :)

```
int compare(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    return strcmp(*(char**)a, *(char**)b);
}

qsort(arr, arr_size, sizeof(char*), compare);
```

Comment: Да можно и массив обернуть в `begin(), end()`.